# Is it good approach to develop a web services in CQ itself?

Tags: web-services, osgi, aem

I need to develop a web services and it needs to be hosted in Adobe CQ. I knew that CQ consume web services from other systems. We will need to create a OSGI bundle for this. I heard that Adobe not recommended to develop web services in CQ. Is it good approach to develop a web services in CQ itself? What happens if we host it in CQ?

Please share your feedback.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise what you mean by web service. You can have a REST webservice which works well in CQ and you can have a SOAP webservice where I wouldn't dare to implement it in CQ/OSGi.

Comment: what I meant is I want to create a webservices and that should be hosted it in CQ. I knew this can be done in CQ. I just want to know what are the pros and cons.

Comment: your question is still not clear - are you asking about internal vs external services?  Or compile the service inside or outside of CQ?